# getting type error for style transform properties when with react-native-reanimated

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm using
"react-native": "0.59.10"
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0"
with typescript
I'm getting type error for transform properties

```js
const Example = () => {
  const { translationX, gestureHandler } = horizontalPanGestureHandler()
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PanGestureHandler {...gestureHandler}>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX: translationX }] }} />
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting[image: Type error]

Comment: What is the value of the translationX?

Comment: It's a reanimated animation value i.e. new Animated.Value(0)

Comment: Have you added it yourself?  `{ translateX: new Animated.Value(0) }`

Comment: yep I have tried added it my self and it results the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update `react-native-reanimated` to latest version (currently `1.13.0`) and problem with `style` and `transform` will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you cannot pass the `transform` directly on the `style` attribute. This is a bug with the `react-native-reanimated`. Please refer to the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/719)

**SOLUTION:**
But you can work around this issue by changing your code like this

```
const Example = () => {
const { translationX, gestureHandler } = horizontalPanGestureHandler()
const transformStyle = {
     transform: [{ translateX: translationX }]
}
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <PanGestureHandler {...gestureHandler}>
         <Animated.View style={[transformStyle, /** You can add other inline styles here **/{color: 'black'}]} />
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
)}
```

Hope this helps!